# How to Draw multiple points in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

What is the proper way to draw a large amount of 2D points scatter (say starting from 100 and till 10000) in SwiftUI application?

I am a complete newbie, only know how to deal with `ContentView`, simple subviews, rectangles and circles, as far as I understand it's not the best way to draw 10000 small circles with `Circle()`, innit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Path to draw the random points like this:

```
ZStack {
    Color.yellow
    GeometryReader { g in
        Path { p in
            for i in 0..<1000 {
                let x = Int.random(in: 0..<Int(g.size.width))
                let y = Int.random(in: 0..<Int(g.size.height))
                p.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x+1, y: y))
            }
        }.stroke(Color.red)
    }
}.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
```

---

**Custom Point Shapes**

For a custom point shapes, use arcs and lines to create subpaths and `fill` the `Path`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow
            GeometryReader { g in
                Path { p in
                    for _ in 0..<100 {
                        let x = Int.random(in: 0..<Int(g.size.width))
                        let y = Int.random(in: 0..<Int(g.size.height))
                        let pt = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                        switch Int.random(in: 0..<3) {
                        case 0:
                            self.drawCircle(in: &p, at: pt, radius: 3)
                        case 1:
                            self.drawStar(in: &p, at: pt, radius: 5)
                        default:
                            self.drawSquare(in: &p, at: pt, width: 5)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .fill(Color.red)
                .clipped()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func drawCircle(in path: inout Path, at point: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + radius, y: point.y))
        path.addArc(center: point, radius: radius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360), clockwise: false)
    }
    
    func drawSquare(in path: inout Path, at point: CGPoint, width: CGFloat) {
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x - width/2, y: point.y - width/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + width/2, y: point.y - width/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + width/2, y: point.y + width/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x - width/2, y: point.y + width/2))
        path.closeSubpath()
    }
    
    func drawStar(in path: inout Path, at point: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(Angle(degrees: 342).radians)),
                              y: point.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: 342).radians))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(Angle(degrees: 126).radians)),
                              y: point.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: 126).radians))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(Angle(degrees: 270).radians)),
                              y: point.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: 270).radians))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(Angle(degrees: 54).radians)),
                              y: point.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: 54).radians))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(Angle(degrees: 198).radians)),
                              y: point.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: 198).radians))))
        path.closeSubpath()
    }

}
```

[image: Drawing running in iPhone 11 simulator]

Comment: This is great, thanks! But unfortunately I didn't find any way to customize point shape.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should mix your SwiftUI application with CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation, or Metal, or SpriteKit or SceneKit (or other engines). Drawing circles and rectangles or other shapes is not really part of a common iOS application except for games. SwiftUI (also UIKit) provides components and solutions for building not fancy but easily usable business applications.
If you want to work on pixel level, check out the technologies above, but most of the apps are not doing that.

I also think that if you are a newbie, you should start creating some "boring starter apps" like a TODO-list app in SwiftUI.
Managing a rendering engine on iOS can be pretty hard to do if you don't really know the iOS environment already.